# Is there an easy way to find what my server "does"?

Tags: ssh, services, top, processes

I received access to some Linux servers to help adding capacity to a network. Now I wonder if there are more ways to examine the server more than just running `top` and see what's running?

If I want to get a good overview while logged in via ssh, is there an informative way to get a quick overview which services and daemons are running and what they are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider using `htop` instead of `top` for a more graphic output.

Then you can use `lsof -p <pid>` to see what files are opened by a service, including network files.
`lsof` has a wide variety of options, I suggest you to consult `man 8 lsof`.

Then you can use `iptop` to look at current network connections, again this tools offer you many options, like showing you the resolved ip addresses of the remote machine your server is connected to or their domain names.

`monitorix` show you system load average and usage, memory allocation, disk driver health, system services, network ports, mail statistics.

If you are concerned by security, [Suricata engine](https://suricata-ids.org/) is "capable of real time intrusion detection (IDS), inline intrusion prevention (IPS), network security monitoring (NSM) and offline pcap processing". It is free and open source.

For a complete tool to monitor almost everything on the machine there is [Collectl](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/), a complete tool to monitor and gather information about Linux system resources as CPU usage, memory, network, inodes, processes, nfs, tcp, sockets. In french we use the expression 'usine à gaz', translated to 'labyrinthine system' for such tools, but it seems very effective.

Answer (score 1):

You really should check for all listening tcp/udp port if you want to know what your server is serving :

```
netstat -ltu
```

l for listening
t for tcp
u for udp

Also to know what services are started at boot time :

```
service --status-all
```

and with systemd

```
systemctl list-units
```

Comment: Good but my system didn't have the `service --status-all` because the service command seems not installed.

Answer (score 1):

My first command would be

```
>netstat -lpunt
```

That lists all listening ports, with the owning process id an program name.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18637/mysqld
```

Oh, look. it's running mysql. Take a look at the defined database names.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8084                 :::*                    LISTEN      18034/java
```

Java. Might be tomcat...

```
>ps ax | grep 18034
18034 ?        Ssl    0:34 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomca
```

yes it is. Go look at /usr/share/tomcat and see what .war files there are.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      20336/httpd
```

Apache. Find the site definition files.

... and so on. Gernally, servers publish their services by IP, so the listening sockets is a good place to start.

If the machine is "busy",

```
iotop -o -d 10
```

will show you what processes are actually hammering the disks.